# Sampling over a defined Probability Distribution

Tags: python

I would like to sample over a particular probability distribution that I define, for example (1+k*cos^2(theta)). I would like to do it in python, but ideas on other languages are welcome. I thought it was possible to create a function that we would do a random sampling from. Maybe too naive of me. Could you give me any tips or suggestions?

Comment: What are `k` and `theta`?

Comment: This question is too broad to be answered... What are you asking ? if it's possible in Python -> yes. If there are other languages able to do that -> yes. How to do that -> too broad (how to create a function ? how to do random ? how to sample ? library for cos ? etc). Try by yourself, and when you are stuck on a specific problem, we'll be glad to help.

Comment: theta is an angle and k is a constant.

Comment: I would like to do it in python. My issue is to sample a user defined function, I have no idea how to do it. All the other points I am fine with.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what you want to achieve? I would assume you want to draw random numbers that are distributed according to this function? You could achieve this by drawing numbers uniformly distributed on [0,1] and use the inverse of your distribution function. I'm happy to help with these steps, but let me know if that's what you want to to...

Comment: I would like to obtain different numbers from a probability distribution. My main problem is how to do: np.random(function) in python. I saw that it works for lists but I have no idea why to do it for functions.

Comment: According to the numpy documentation, np.random.random() returns random floats in the half-open interval [0.0, 1.0). As you said, you can pass a list to this function, but this will NOT draw random elements in the list...

Comment: I would suggest you take a look at the Scipy package. It comes with a lot of different probability distributions you can pick from. If the desired function is not included in the package, you could try to go the inverse route.

Comment: I have checked all functions of the scipy package. I even tried to just find just a polynomial function. At this point I will forget to try to find a python function and try to code the integral method to do the sampling. :)